# Regex End of Line and Specific Chracters

Tags: python, regex, pyserial

So I'm writing a Python program that reads lines of serial data, and compares them to a dictionary of line codes to figure out which specific lines are being transmitted.  I am attempting to use a Regular Expression in order to filter out the extra garbage line serial read string has on it, but I'm having a bit of an issue.

Every single code in my dictionary looks like this: `T12F8B0A22**F8`.  The asterisks are the two alpha numeric pieces that differentiate each string code.

This is what I have so far as my regex: `'/^T12F8B0A22[A-Z0-9]{2}F8$/'`

I am getting a few errors with this however.  My first error, is that there are some characters are the end of the string I still need to get rid of, which is odd because I thought `$/` denoted the end of the line in regex.  However when I run my code through the debugger I notice that after running through the following code:

```
#regexString contains the serial read line data
regexString = re.sub('/^T12F8B0A22[A-Z0-9]{2}F8$/', '', regexString)
```

My string looks something like this: `'T12F8B0A2200F8\\r'`

I need to get rid of the `\\r`.

If for some reason I can't get rid of this with regex, how in python do you send specific string character through an argument?  In this case I suppose it would be length - 3?

Comment: Only a few errors? Well, I doubt it works at all due to the regex delimiters. You must remove `/`s. Note that `$` is a zero-width assertion, you need to add `[\r\n]*` after `$` to consume any line break chars. Try `'(?m)^T12F8B0A22[A-Z0-9]{2}F8$[\r\n]*'`

Comment: Removing the `/`'s make it work even worse :\  Edit: thanks for the help, but your suggestion isn't fixing the problem, in fact it undid a lot of the string trimming I had actually working.

Comment: The r tag means the r language -- suggest you remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is threefold:

1) your string contains extra `\r` (Carriage Return character) before `\n` (New Line character); this is common in Windows and in network communication protocols; it is probably best to remove any trailing whitespace from your string:

```
regexString = regexString.rstrip()
```

2) as mentioned by Wiktor Stribiżew, your regexp is unnecessarily surrounded with `/` characters - some languages, like Perl, define regexp as a string delimited by `/` characters, but Python is not one of them;

3) your instruction using `re.sub` is actually replacing the matching part of `regexString` with an empty string - I believe this is the exact opposite of what you want (you want to **keep** the match and remove everything else, right?); that's why fixing the regexp makes things "even worse".

To summarize, I think you should use this instead of your current code:

```
m = re.match('T12F8B0A22[A-Z0-9]{2}F8', regexString)
regexString = m.group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get rid of the "\r", but first a little analysis of your code :
1. the special charakter for the end is just '$' not '$\' in python.
2. re.sub will substitute the matched pattern with a string ( '' in your case) wich would substitute the string you want to get with an empty string and you are left with the //r

possible solutions:

1. use simple replace:

   ```
    regexString.replace('\\r','')
   ```
2. if you want to stick to regex the approach is the same

   ```
   pattern = '\\\\r'         
   match = re.sub(pattern, '',regexString)
   ```

2.2 if you want the acces the different groubs use re.search

```
    match = re.search('(^T12F8B0A22[A-Z0-9]{2}F8)(.*)',regexString)
    match.group(1) # will give you the T12...
    match.groupe(2) # gives you the \\r
```

Answer (score 0):

Just match what you want to find.  Couple of examples:

```
import re

data = '''lots of
otherT12F8B0A2212F8garbage
T12F8B0A2234F8around
T12F8B0A22ABF8the
stringsT12F8B0A22CDF8
'''

print(re.findall('T12F8B0A22..F8',data))
```

> ['T12F8B0A2212F8', 'T12F8B0A2234F8', 'T12F8B0A22ABF8', 'T12F8B0A22CDF8']

```
m = re.search('T12F8B0A22..F8',data)
if m:
    print(m.group(0))
```

> T12F8B0A2212F8